# Finding duplicate records and leaving out if newest has later date

Tags: ms-access

So right to the chase...
I have a table of event projects.  I won't get into the other tables.

The main table looks like

```
Event ID      EVENT TITLE       PROJECT START        EVENT DATE
1             Basketball        4/24/2015            6/24/2015
2             Soccer            4/25/2015            6/25/2015
3             Volleyball        5/25/2015            7/25/2015
4             Basketball        7/10/2015            9/10/2015
5             Soccer            7/11/2015            9/11/2015
```

My macro to show current projects just applies filter to [EVENT DATE] >= Now()

I'm trying to show events not currently scheduled.  I tried [EVENT DATE] <= Now() but that just shows past events.  So if record 5 above did not exist, I would want the macro to display Soccer.  I'm using a Split Form for this with buttons for the macros btw.

I'm not sure if I need to utilize the main event table or not, which looks like:

```
ID            TITLE            ADDRESS
1             Basketball       XXX Street name
2             Soccer           XXX Street name
3             Volleyball       XXX Street name
```

Any help is appreciate thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL statement that does what you want:
SELECT Title
FROM Main_Events
WHERE Title not in
(
 SELECT Main.Event_Title
FROM Main
WHERE (((Main.EventDate)>=Now()))
 );

The inner query selects the events from the Main table that have future dates. The outer query selects the events from the event list that are NOT IN the results of the inner query.

Note: Today is July 27 and the Volleyball event in your question is no longer a future event.